# Want Clear a cell in an Excel Table based on choice of a dropdown validation list in the same row, while updating similar Items based on that choice

Tags: excel, vba

I am building a very complex working book in excel and trying make it as user friendly as possible.

So I have table example below that as 3 columns call Tbltst.

The three columns are Control #, Dollars, and Returned.

Control # is auto populated, Dollars is user entered and Returned is Validation drop-drown.

When I change the Value from N to Y in Returned I am looking to have all the amounts in the Dollars column to change to 0 for that Control# and the other entries Returned to change to Match.

So say I change the first 1234 in the list.  That $50 dollars should be blanked and Rows 3 and 6s Dollars should be blanked also and their returned column Updated to Y to match row 1.

Other information, the workbook is locked and Control# is not editable (formula driven as mentioned above) but both Dollars and Returned are editable.

[image: Workbook]

I am not proficient enough in VBA to try much, I did try using formulas but to set a cell based on what is above requires a Macro and I am very much a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User's input in `Returned` column tirggers `Worksheet_Change` to update the data.

> [Worksheet.Change event (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngTab As Range
    Set rngTab = ActiveSheet.Range("Tbltst")
    If Not Intersect(Target, rngTab) Is Nothing Then
        With Target
            If .CountLarge = 1 And .Cells(1).Column = 3 Then
                If UCase(.Value) = "Y" Then
                    Dim sKey, c
                    sKey = Cells(.Row, 1)
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                    For Each c In rngTab.Columns(1).Cells
                        If c.Value = sKey Then
                            Cells(c.Row, 2) = 0
                            Cells(c.Row, 3) = "Y"
                        End If
                    Next
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you that seems to work for me.  I just need to add in multiple choices that will fire it.  But I can follow you shared enough.